# platform specific css Ionic 2

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am creating app on ionic where UI is looking good on Android but it is not ok for Ios.. I have header bar like

```
 <ion-toolbar class="subheader" >
    <ion-title class="subheader0">STEP 1 </ion-title>
    <ion-title class="subheader1">Verify your details to proceed. </ion-title>
    <ion-title class="subheader2">Continue</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
```

This is showing in Android but only last line (continue) is showing on ios subheader. Now what to do in platform specific css ?

Comment: Can you post your css file with subheader classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

platform specific css is written with the prefixes wrapped around the relevant sass

**windows**

```
.wp{
  /// styles
}
```

**android**

```
.md{
  /// styles
  // default style during developmnent
}
```

**apple**

```
.ios{
  /// styles
}
```

the default development style can be changed in the `app.module.ts`

```
imports: [
   IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp,{
          mode:'ios'
   }), 
]
```

[Ionic docs reference](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/platform-specific-styles/)

In order to modify the toolbar you can target the ionic sass variables for the toolbar specifically

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toolbar/Toolbar/#sass-variables

Comment: <button ion-button full color="green">Full Button</button> this is the basic ionic code for android and ios. Here i want to change 'color red' in ios app instead of  green. Then how to re-write the code only for ios